# tensorflow - TFRecordWriter takes up too much memory when writing to a file?

Tags: python, for-loop, memory, tensorflow, iterator

I'm working on a large dataset, which has 306400 images to be processed.

But the thing I'm to do is really simple: resize the image and then write to a `.TFRecords` file.

However, I got an `out of memory` error.

I can't run the script several times since the `.TFRecord` file cannot be appended, so I have to write all data in one run.

I've tried to use several `for` loops because I thought after each `for` loop the memory used would be released but it seemed I was wrong.

So I then tried to use `iter()` to get iterators since for `dict` objects using `dict.iteritems()` can save memory, comparing to `dict.iter()`.

But no magic.

So now I have no idea how to solve the problem.

```
def gen_records(record_name, img_path_file, label_map):
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(record_name)
    classes = []

    with open(label_map, 'r') as f:
        for l in f.readlines():
            classes.append(l.split(',')[0])

    with open(img_path_file, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        num_images = len(lines)
    print 'total number to be written' + str(num_images)
    print 'start writing...'

    patches = []
    with open(img_path_file, 'r') as f:
        for patch in f.readlines():
            patches.append(patch[:-1])

    cnt = 0
    for patch in patches:
        cnt += 1
        # print '[' + str(cnt) + ' / ' + str(num_images) + ']' + 'writing  ' + str()
        img = tf.image.resize_images(np.array(Image.open(patch)), (224, 224), method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR)
        img_raw = np.array(img).tostring()
        label = classes.index(patch.split('/')[1])
        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
            'label': _int64_feature(int(label)),
            'image': _bytes_feature(img_raw)
        }))

        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

    writer.close()
```

How can I "release" the memory used after every iteration? Or how can I save the memory?

Comment: The call to `iter` on line 55 is needless and does not safe memory at all, since the original list is still there. You could instead define a generator that yields the patches.

Comment: The problem might be that you try to load all 306400 pics into memory in order to save them with one single call to `write`. This means that even if each pic was only 100 KB in size, you would need more than 30 GB of working memory. The error indicates that you memory is to small for your data set.

Comment: I edited the code and try to execute `write` in every loop, but still, the memory used keep increasing. The problem is, I thought that if I use a `for` loop, then every image get opened and processed and in the next loop, the memory used would be cleaned automatically but it doesn't. Is there any method that I can load the pics separately?

Comment: @MaxPowers Also, in the edited code, the variables should be re-assigned in every loop, so where does the huge used memory belong to?

Comment: It's `tensorflow` that eats your memory, not your Python code. You'll have to dig deeper into the module to figure out what's not releasing the memory here, my bet is on `tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter`.

Comment: @zwer I also think it is the writer that takes up too much memory, but it seems the writer doesn't have things like `flush()`. I don't understand why the `writer.write()` doesn't seem to write data to the file at every call.

Comment: It's weird that `Flush()` is available on the C++  side in [tensorflow::core::lib::io::RecordWriter](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/lib/io/record_writer.h) but is not exposed in the [Python bindings](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/lib/io/py_record_writer.h). However, following that trail, it appears that it keeps a `zlib` buffer but that buffer is definitely nowhere near the memory usage numbers you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to try is to load each pic on demand. Delete the lines that load the pics (lines 15 to 18) and define the following function outside `gen_records`:

```
def generate_patches():
    with open('testfile.txt', 'r') as f:
        for patch in f.readlines():
            yield patch[:-1]
```

Then replace the definition of the for loop by

```
for patch in generate_patches():
    ...
```

Comment: I'm already using generators with yield etc and still running out of memory, it seems to be building the whole dataset in memory before writing it out.